# Esci vs scopus ? Which one to follow

Tags: publications

Which are considered as trustworthy good quality  journals , the ones indexed in esci by web of science or are the ones indexed in scopus ? There are some journals which us indexed in esci and not in scopus and vice versa. Any lead points on this ?

Comment: The ones that publish good research.

Comment: There are no trustworthy journals: all journals do publish some junk. There are trustworthy authors though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an expert on this, but my understanding of the two are:

**ESCI** aka. Emerging Sources Citation Index is a "lower-ranked" index. Journals listed here are being considered for the more prestigious indices SCIE, SSCI, and AHCI (note this doesn't include SCI, which is the most prestigious index). In other words, ESCI is a "feeder" index to the SCIE/SSCI/AHCI, which in turn feed into SCI. If you [search the ESCI](http://mjl.clarivate.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi), you'll find that the most prestigious journals such as *Physical Review Letters* aren't actually indexed here.

**Scopus** is fundamentally different and is built more on inclusiveness than quality. If you look at the [inclusion criteria](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/content/content-policy-and-selection), Scopus mostly demands regular publication, peer review, diversity in authors & editors, and online availability. It does require that the journal's articles also be cited by other journals in Scopus, but not more than that. Scopus has many, many more journals than ESCI.

So which is good? Hard to say, and depends on what you mean by 'good'. Good journals will be in Scopus, but being in Scopus doesn't mean a journal is good. Being in ESCI is a different matter, since the really good journals won't be in it, but the really bad ones won't be in it either. It's your judgment call to make.