# should I publish in journal that has no IF

Tags: journals, disreputable-publishers

I have written an article in the field of Information Systems and Security and I would like to publish it in a journal. From downloading the Scimago journal rank, I decided to publish in a journal called [International Journal of Intelligent Information Technologies (IJIIT)](https://www.igi-global.com/journal/international-journal-intelligent-information-technologies/1089). The scope of the journal is really promising for my paper and appears to be in the quartile Q3 of Scimago.

My concern with the journal is that it has really low bibliometrics, I didn't find its Impact Factor, and and has an H-index of 12. The only thing the journal has is something called "Emerging Sources Citation Index". Wikipedia says that most journals with the Emerging Sources Citation Index index are **predatory** **journals**.

- Is publishing in journals with no Impact Factor a bad thing for my carrier?
- Can I verify whether this journal a predatory journal or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot behind your question that should be clarified.

- You are not finding an impact factor for the journal because it is not indexed in Science Citation Index (SCI). All journals not indexed by SCI do not have an impact factor. SCI has its criteria for indexing, one of which is whether papers published in the journal receive citations from the other journals already in the index. Not having an impact factor is usually a bad sign in the sense that the journal is not prestigious. It does NOT mean that the journal is predatory.
- [ESCI is a lower-ranking index.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/110028/esci-vs-scopus-which-one-to-follow) Journals listed here are being considered for the more prestigious indices. Notably the ESCI does not feed into the SCI, but to the "next tier" of citation indices. If the best the journal can say is that it's indexed by ESCI, it's definitely not a prestigious journal.
- I don't know what HSCX is and can't find it via Google, but assuming it's got to do with the h-index then it literally means nothing. A h-index of 12 means that the 12 most cited papers published by that journal/person have been cited at least 12 times each. Since this calculation is so generic, the moment a single paper is published, it can be calculated. If you've ever written a paper before, you have a h-index.
- Quoting a h-index on the website does not mean that the journal is predatory. Predatory publishers do something completely different, the most important hallmark being they publish without really performing peer review. They can afford to publish junk because the authors pay for it (i.e. open access). Since the journal you linked is subscription-based, I can virtually guarantee it is not predatory.

**tl; dr: the journal is likely to be low-prestige, but it is almost surely not predatory.**

As to specific questions:

> Is publishing in journals with no Impact Factor a bad thing for my carrier?

Usually, yes. The more prestigious the venue of publication the more people read it and the better it's regarded.

> Can I verify whether this journal a predatory journal or not?

[Yes. See this question.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam)

Comment: So the journal is not predatory. But honestly, is this a journal that you would usually recommend? I've spent more than 9 months submitting and dealing with desk-rejections (out-of-scope). I've tried many tools, but I only managed to pass the first editorial assessment once in a prestigious journal (I've got pretty good review, they rejected the paper but all said that  my approach "has merit and pretty reasonable"). Long story short, I am back to looking for journals and I don't want to waste another 9 months. This is why I started looking for journals with a more general scope.

Comment: @U.User If you have spent 9 months on desk rejections, then you are doing something tremendously wrong, and you probably need guidance from someone more experienced with the field.

Comment: @U.User I can't give you a recommendation for which journal to publish in, because I haven't seen your paper and don't know your field. As Tobias Kildetoft suggested, ask someone with more experience in your subject.

Comment: Well at first, I have made the mistake of submitting without paying careful attention to the scope of the journal. But later, I have started to be more methodological, we've changed the structure of the paper many times, we even added more case-studies. The problem with paper is the variety of tools it uses (Information security solutions, Mobile Agents, and performance evaluation). The paper was examined by my two supervisors and we even discussed the contribution with a specialized engineer. I think the problem is that I do not know how to find proper journals and I have bad luck too.